# Changing parameters in a JAX-WS web service

Tags: java, parameters, jax-ws

I'm creating some web services using JAX-WS and the java SE build-in server. Every time I add a new parameter on a web service i need to change the URL it's published to. Otherwise the new parameters always get a null value. How can I make this work without changing the URL?

Here's the main class code with the publishing code:

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import pickate.AmazonMail;
import pickate.FacebookStream;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/pickate/amazonmail", new AmazonMail());
    Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8888/pickate/facebookstream", new FacebookStream());

    }
}
```

And the implementation of one of the webservices

```
package pickate;

import java.util.List;
import javax.jws.Oneway;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
// Other imports go here

@WebService
public class FacebookStream
{

    public FacebookStream()
    {
    }

    @WebMethod
    @Oneway
    public void sendNotification(
        @WebParam(name = "receivers") List<String> receivers,
        @WebParam(name = "fbtoken") String fbtoken,
        @WebParam(name = "body") String body,
        )
    {
        // Some interesting stuff goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be that the tool you're using to send the messages is not picking the latests wsdl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was indeed the client caching up the WSDL file. It seems the PHP Soap Extension (which is what i'm using on the client-side) does it by default.